Arabic Hashtag in Facebook Sharer Adds Unwanted Characters (e.g., ?__eep__=6)
I'm trying to implement a Facebook share button in my Next.js application with a pre-filled Arabic hashtag, but I'm running into an issue.
Here is the code I'm using:
const handleShare = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (score) {
    const shareParams = new URLSearchParams({
      u: shareUrl,
      hashtag: "#هاشتاگێکی_دیاریکراو",
    }).toString();

    const fbShareUrl = `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?${shareParams}`;

    // Open share dialog
    window.open(
      fbShareUrl,
      "_blank",
      "width=600,height=400,left=" +
        (window.innerWidth - 600) / 2 +
        ",top=" +
        (window.innerHeight - 400) / 2
    );
  }
};

The issue is that when I click the hashtag in Facebook after sharing the post, the URL of the hashtag changes. For example, this is what I get:
http://facebook.com/hashtag/هاشتاگێکی_دیاریکراو?__eep__=6
The added ?__eep__=6 parameter breaks the hashtag. If I manually remove ?eep=6 from the URL in the browser, the hashtag works correctly.
I have tried these approaches:

Encoding the hashtag (encodeURIComponent("#هاشتاگێکی_دیاریکراو"))
Removing the # sign

Still none of these works.

The same URL parameter gets appended when the hashtag is not in Arabic, but contains ASCII characters only. Why these URLs with an Arabic hashtag break on their end - you'd have to ask Facebook. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/
